# Which Java libraries do HTTP Accept Header Parsing?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

Which Java libraries parse HTTP `Accept` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the HttpClient [`Util.parseHeader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) method.

---

**Edit:** (trying to make this answer worth being accepted post-factum)

The spring framework provides this functionality within its [MediaType](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) component.

If you are already using Spring MVC you can simply request for a `@RequestHeader`-annotated parameter of type `HttpHeaders` and access the list of accepted media types by simply calling [HttpHeaders.getAccept()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#getAccept--).

Comment: If you use Jakarta / Jersey : HttpHeaderReader.readAcceptMediaType(value)

Answer (score 13):

You should read this article : http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/06/08/restful.html

The article uses Python but it's not a problem : at the end, the following link is shared : http://code.google.com/p/mimeparse

As you can see, "mimeparse" is :

> Basic functions for handling mime-types in Erlang, JavaScript, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, **Java**

According to the home page :

```
List<String> mimeTypesSupported = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(
            "application/xbel+xml,text/xml", ','));
String bestMatch = MIMEParse.bestMatch(mimeTypesSupported, "text/*;q=0.5,*/*;q=0.1");
```

Comment: MIMEParse is exactly what I'm looking for, but it's not available in Maven Central, unfortunately...

Comment: It's not important : mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<theGroupIdYouWant> -DartifactId=<theArtifactIdYouWant> -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=<theVersion> -Dfile=</path/to/jar> -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: Another solution is to use a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva ... ... ... But the easiest solution is to install the jar with maven install:install-file

Comment: You can just copy MIMEParse.java to your project and use it at will, it's MIT-licensed.

Comment: FWIW: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.commonjava.mimeparse/mimeparse

Comment: See Guava's [MediaType](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html) for a Java parser.