# How to distinguish html vs xhr/xml/json requests in Compojure/Ring?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

How to distinguish between html vs xhr/xml/json requests in Compojure/Ring similar to respond_to in Rails?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you do want to explicitly distinguish based on Accept header - and not simply return the appropriate response type as per Ankur's answers, you could create your own dispatch function like the following.

```
(defn dispatch [m]
  (let [req     (ring-request)
        accept  (get (:headers req) "accept")
        accept? #(re-find (re-pattern (str "^" %)) accept)
        key     (cond
                 (accept? "application/json") :json
                 (accept? "text/html")        :html
                 :else                        :default)]
    ((key m))))
```

and then invoke it like so

```
(defpage "/foo" []
  (dispatch {:json (fn [] "{}")
             :html (fn [] "html")
             :default (fn [] "default")}))
```

The `accept?` function above is a bit primitive, but it may serve as a starting point.

Comment: Where does the `defpage` macro come from? Is this part of Compojure or Ring. I found some traces to Noir only.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a Ring middleware that can handle the Accept Header MIME type and convert the response map data value to the appropriate MIME.

Check out : [ring-middleware-format](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation you reference mentions,

> Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept
>   header submitted by the client.

Your code, too, can look at the `Accept` header and decide what to send based on its contents, which you can get by indexing into the request object.  The interesting question is whether there is an easy way of parsing the header and taking it apart.

You might find some information on this in the answers to *[Is there some Java library for Accept HTTP header parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705979/is-there-some-java-library-for-accept-http-header-parsing)*.

Comment: The question was specifically about Compojure/Ring

Comment: @Sathish You can get at the `Accept` header by doing `(get-in request [:headers "accept"])` where `request` is the request object passed to your handler. That's what I meant by “indexing into the request object.”